# Check email template after meta tag replacement and before sending in Mandrill

Tags: php, mandrill

I am been looking around and cannot seem to find a way that I can check an email's html before I send it in Mandrill.

Ideally I want to be able to replace the merge tags and then check the email's display before sending it.

I am using Mandrill PHP.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this over the API with the `render` method.

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.php.html#method=render