# Mandrill mergetags: send email only when all merge tags are replaced

Tags: email, mailchimp, mandrill, email-templates

This question is related to this [Check email template after meta tag replacement and before sending in Mandrill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374290/check-email-template-after-meta-tag-replacement-and-before-sending-in-mandrill).

I would like to know if there is a way to configure the Mandrill to send an email only when all the merge tags in the email template have been replaced. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this isn't possible to configure with Mandrill.

You can (maybe *should*) perform this using the API however - take advantage of the `render` method to pre-render the outgoing email, and then look for any un-replaced fields.

```
function has_merge_tags($string)
{
    return ( strpos("|*", $string) === false AND strpos("*|", $string) === false);
}

function send_email($template_code, $merge_fields)
{
    $mandrill = new Mandrill(APIKEY);

    // pre-render the template with the merged fields
    $result = $mandrill->templates->render($name, array(), $merge_fields);

    if (has_merge_tags($result['html']))
    {
        // throw exception, log it, whatever
    }

    really_send_email($result['html']);   
}
```

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.php.html#method=render